# Can you remove one community rather than the entire account?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

So like, if I have a profile on puzzling.StackExchange.com and StackOverflow.com, can I remove myself from the puzzling.SE community, rather than deleting my entire account?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by default submitting a deletion request will only delete the profile on the site where you submitted the request. It does not affect other sites on the network.